# Meteor Single Sign On

Tags: node.js, authentication, meteor, single-sign-on

I need single sign on as part of the requirements for a Meteor application. I have tried `ldapjs` usign the npm module on Meteor, with no luck however. Any ideas?

I haven't tried using passport...

Comment: SSO for every system or just the usual suspects?

Comment: If you end up needing to implement one of your own, [this](http://meteorhacks.com/extending-meteor-accounts.html) is a good resource to get started with.

Comment: @David Did any solution help you?

Comment: Sorry, it's been a busy week. So for some reason, I don't need to connect to the usual suspects, but now I have to connect to Active Directory... :(

Answer (score 0):

The meteor `Accounts` [API](http://docs.meteor.com/#accounts_api) already comes with some handy SSO for the [usual suspects](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_loginwithexternalservice) (including `facebook`, `googleOAuth`, `github`, `twitter`) seamlessly integrated with the `accounts-ui`-[package](http://docs.meteor.com/#accountsui).

For further integration, account-packages can be found on the package management site [`atmosphere`](https://atmosphere.meteor.com/) including

1. extension for [`github`](https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/accounts-github)
2. [`steam`](https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/accounts-steam)
3. [`foursquare`](https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/accounts-foursquare)
4. and many more e.g. `bitbucket`, `trello`, `asana` etc.